# Multiline Label in extjs?

Tags: extjs, label

How can I specify a `maxWidth` for a label but have the label keep adding lines until all the text is shown? Using ExtJs 6.0.2 Classic toolkit.

Comment: `label` is a really lightweight component that should not live on its own, all the layout of the label is done by the `labelable` mixin of the form field. What are you trying to achieve? Is a `container` instead of a `label` an option? You can put text (or anything else) into the `html` config of a `container`, and the `container` has everything you need for layouting.

Comment: Yes, I am now using a `panel` with an `html` config that just holds text, however the annoying padding of the `html` config is making things difficult to align

Comment: Which padding? Cannot reproduce, please show in a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/22nb).

Comment: Oops, I had `<p>my text</p>` and the tags were automatically adding it